# Change or Access Vue.js method from external script

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue app that is built on the Webpack. The component has a couple of simple computed propertys like getting sum amount from inputs.
But now I need to make it possible to replace the summation function from an external file not related to the current assembly, as well as the ability to add buttons (and) other functions from this file to the current template - subtraction, multiplication, division depending on the flags (hide / show) set from the external file.
What is the best way to approach it? Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: The absolute best way would be to rework your Vue component to handle this. The approach that you are currently going for is **not** architecturally sound. This is going to create external dependencies, which as your code base grows, will more than likely cause major headaches for you. Alternatively, create a new Vue component to act as a wrapper and encapsulate your external script, and your other component.

Comment: In a real-life project I agree, but it is a technical test prior to the interview. So far I coudn't figure out anything better than pushing functions from external js file to localstorage

Comment: Yikes... if that is the interview question, I am scared of what they are doing in their projects. You could expose the function via the `window` object? `window.myCrazyFunction = () => { // code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's a bad idea to have your functions outside your **.vue** components. That way it's much easier to create pure components, and just export those functions from those files - your **.vue** components can import them. (But I think it's an opinionated pattern you either use or don't use.)

The snippet below only shows that it's simple to add external functions to **Vue** components (or instance in this case):

```js
const sumFunction = (a, b) => {
  return a + b
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    result() {
      return sumFunction(Number(this.a), Number(this.b))
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      a: 0,
      b: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="a" /><br />
  <input type="number" v-model="b" /><br /> a + b = {{result}}
</div>
```

So, your files could look something like this:

**externalFunction.js:**

```
export const sumFunction = (a, b) => {
  return a + b
}
```

**sumTemplate.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="number" v-model="a" /><br />
    <input type="number" v-model="b" /><br />
    a + b = {{result}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { sumFunction } from "@externalFunction"

export default {
  computed: {
    result() {
      return sumFunction(Number(this.a), Number(this.b))
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      a: 0,
      b: 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The only thing that should be emphasized: **with this setup unit tests have an even more important role**. You have to watch for inputs and outputs of your functions, so when you change them no components would break.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help. Don't forget that **VueJS** does a lot of things for you, but **it's JavaScript under the hood** - that means **you can do anything that JS allows you to do**.